# pdf figure only partly shown in PDF document

Tags: graphics

My problem concerns figures only showing **partly** in the pdf document. It seams as if there was something covering the image except for a little bit that is shown.
I use \includegraphics with an image pdf file. Compile with pdflatex and it show ok in the dvi file. In the pdf file that is imediatly built there are no images whatsoever. But if I convert the dvi into pdf a little portion of the figure is visible.
I would very much apreciate if you could help me with this.
Maria Silva

Comment: we need a MWE of your code.

Comment: @touhami Probably not in this case....

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting a `.dvi`, you are not compiling with pdfLaTeX. You are using LaTeX. LaTeX cannot use `.pdf` images. There must be errors in your console output - reading them would help you diagnose the trouble. In general, the messages posted there can tell you useful things. Not always and sometimes it is hard to understand. But it is always worth at least taking a look at the error! In this case, it probably either complained that it could not find the image or made some complaint about that image. Or look in the `.log` file.

The solution, in any case, is to use `pdflatex`.

Look at the first line of the console output when you compile. If you are using `latex`, you will have something like this:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded format=latex)
```

If you are using `pdflatex`, you will have something like this:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
```

It is the `format` you need to check - it will say `pdfTeX` in both cases.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Pdflatex didn't work. But I converted to eps format and all the figures appear correctly on the DVI file. However, when I convert the DVI into PDF ( I am using WinEdt 7.1) all figures disappear except 3 which are specified with width and height parameters whereas the ones that disappear use the bb, scale and clip parameters. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: @MariaSilva Without an example? No. But if you are starting with PDF images, it makes no sense to convert them into EPS, use LaTeX and then convert the DVI. Saying that pdfLaTeX 'didn't work' tells nothing: what happened? Your computer grew legs and ran away? You got an error? No errors, but your cat ate the output?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. with pdflatex the images don't show in the pdf file, just anempty space in the place where the figure should be. I get no error messages. The command I am using is \includegraphics[bb=-470 280 1970 510,scale=.7,clip]{c:/indices.pdf}

Comment: @MariaSilva What does the log say? Don't specify the file extension. Try putting the images in your working directory so you can just say `\includegraphics...{indices}`.

Comment: Thank you. I took out the file extension and I got the following log:    File: c:/indices.eps Graphic file (type eps)
 <c:/indices.eps>
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `OMS/cmr/m/n' in size <6> not available
(Font)              Font shape `OMS/cmsy/m/n' tried instead on input line 457.

Overfull \hbox (1324.3975pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 454--461
 The result was the same: no image in the final pdf file. For some reason the includegraphics only finds the images when they are in the root c:\. If I put them in the working directory I got an error message saying it cannot find the file.

Comment: That's the console output - just warnings. ***Put the image in your working directory for simplicity.*** Are you compiling with `latex` rather than `pdflatex`?

Comment: Thanks. As I said in my previous message, if i put the image in the working directory i receive an error message saying it cannot find the file and stops compiling.     I am using pdflatex.      If I use latex I also don't get error messages but the result is really strange: only a little bit of the image shows  (the rest is blank - looking as if something was covering  the image almost completely) in the pdf final file.   The DVI is perfect.

Comment: Sorry. That makes no sense. If you say `\includegraphics{indices}`, it will look for a suitable image in the working directory. The other messages you posted have nothing to do with images - at least, the overfull box might, but probably doesn't, and the others definitely don't. Without an example of what you're doing, it is just unclear what is going on. Try to create an MWE using one of the standard images (e.g. `example-image-a` from the `mwe` package).